# Copy color buffer to depth buffer

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am currently attempting to modify someone else's code (minecraft) and I only have access to the color and depth buffers.

How do I copy the color buffer to the depth buffer without creating any other buffers or textures?

**Extra information:**
I wish to write a shader that will take the input from the color buffer (after rendering has finished), modify it, and return it to the color buffer. I believe the best way to do this would be to copy the color buffer to the depth buffer (I don't need the data in the depth buffer anymore), then use the depth buffer as the input to the shader.

Comment: What is the format of the depth buffer? Does it have enough precision to store your colour buffer? Do you need RGBA or just RGB?

Comment: What is it exactly you try to accomplish? I don't see why you'd want to go that route (color→depth→color).

Comment: If you have the ability to insert shader code into Minecraft, then you have the ability to insert arbitrary GL function calls into Minecraft. So what's the problem with using FBOs and such?